# How change the background color in a Word doc?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wanted to know how can I change the background color of the text in Word on all my doc. For exemple I got some text with blue/red/pink background color and I want that the bg color of all my doc white.

I got and exemple for the font color :

```
Sub color()
'
' color Macro
'
'

Dim Plage As Object, Wrd As Object
 
Set Plage = ActiveDocument.Content.Words
 
For Each Wrd In Plage
    If Wrd.Font.color = RGB(0, 0, 255) Then _
    Wrd.Font.color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
Next Wrd
 

End Sub
```

But I don't know how to apply this VBA code for the background color.
Maybe with `Document.Background property` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three background color settings you have to deal with:

- You can have text marked with a *Text Highlight*. This can be modified with `Range.HighlightColorIndex`. To remove the highlight, use `wdNoHighlight`
- You can have *Shading*. Shading is set on paragraph level can can be modified with `Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor`.  To remove it, use `wdColorAutomatic`
- You can have set the background color of a whole document. This can be modified using `Background.Fill` of the document. Either set the `ForeColor` to white, or set the `visible`-property to false.

To clean everything at once, use something like this:

```
Sub RemoveBackgroundColor()
    With ActiveDocument.Content
        .HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
        .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
    End With
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
End Sub
```